# associative products on matrix algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What are all the associative products on the matrix algebra $M_n(\mathbb{C})$? Is there any classification available? Any reference available related to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any bijective map $f:M_n(\mathbb{C})\to M_n(\mathbb{C})$, and set $$M*_fN=f(f^{-1}(M)f^{-1}(N)).$$ Then $*_f$ is associative with unit element $f(I_n)$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Do all associative products arises in this way?

Comment: @budi Certainly not. Let $\mathcal M=M_n(\mathbb C)$. Since $f$ is bijective, $$\mathcal M\ast_f\mathcal M=f(f^{-1}(\mathcal M)f^{-1}(\mathcal M))=f(\mathcal M\mathcal M)=f(\mathcal M)=\mathcal M.$$ So, at the very least, every associative product $\circ$ on $\mathcal M$ such that $\mathcal M\circ\mathcal M\ne\mathcal M$ cannot be expressed as some $\ast_f$. E.g. $\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}\circ\pmatrix{x&y\\ z&w}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\pmatrix{ax&0\\ 0&0}$ is one such associative product.

Answer (score 1):

This is a boring answer but if $A, B$ are complex matrixes, the product defined by $A \bigodot B := (a_{ij}) \bigodot (b_{ij}) = (a_{ij}*b_{ij})$ is associative.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: +1 Although "Community Bot" found this answer unclear, it looks perfectly clear and correct to me. The only potential problem is the use of * for multiplication, which, though common in computing, is rare in mathematics